# My table contains 30 fields, How can I display that on a web page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql table called 'songs' that contains 30 fields and I have a 'song_list.php' page with the width of 800px. I have already implemented it but its seems too crowded. Is there any way to efficiently (easy to read) display the fields.

Comment: You could hide some fields and put it in a div or something. Then you can make it so that when you click the song it will expand or when you click some kind of button it will expand and show the rest of the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like to make excessively long titles links smaller & only show whats needed title, date,cat, sml desc,price ect

```
function _substr($str, $length, $minword = 3){
    $sub = '';
    $len = 0;
    foreach (explode(' ', $str) as $word)
    {
        $part = (($sub != '') ? ' ' : '') . $word;
        $sub .= $part;
        $len += strlen($part);
        if (strlen($word) > $minword && strlen($sub) >= $length)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $sub . (($len < strlen($str)) ? '...' : '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Record 1
    key    value
    key    value
    key    value
    key    value
    ...

Record 2
    key    value
    key    value
    key    value
    key    value
    ...

Record 3
    key    value
    key    value
    key    value
    key    value
    ...

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Show only the important stuff, and the rest on mouse over, or in a separate popup window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pagination` with `view more` option

Answer (score 1):

I would triage what the most useful fields are for immediate viewing. Those are the only fields I would display by default. Then have a "more" button of some sort.  If clicked, I'm partial to popping up information in a modal dialog.  That way any clicks or modifications are still easy to handle via javascript.

If you aren't comfortable rolling your own modal for a project like this, or need somewhere to start, check out this modal dialog roundup.  http://komunitasweb.com/2009/03/jquery-modal-box-round-up/

Answer (score 0):

Hi with the same problem I used one jQuery plugin called **custom scroller**

**[Check this out](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)**